# Passing command line arguments to concatenated python ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, conda

I have a Dockerfile based on `FROM continuumio/miniconda3` with an ENTRYPOINT which concatenates the `source activate <env> && python my_script.py` commands, like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate env && python my_script.py" ]
```

I'm trying to pass command line arguments to my_script using `docker run` as follows:

```
docker run -it my_image "foo" "bar"
```

But these aren't passed on to the script. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Note that if I change the entry point to `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate env && python my_script.py foo bar" ]`, this works! But that's not what I want: inputs foo and bar can be different for different container instances.

I also tried to put the source activate env and python commands in a separate shell script, and then tried:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "my_shell_script.sh" ]
```

(where the shell script calls `source activate env and python my_script.py $1 $2` in sequence)

But this tells me that `/opt/conda/envs/env` is not a conda environment!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to find what out what's wrong.

First of all, you were correct to assume that anything after `docker run <image>` will be appended to the ENTRYPOINT command.

However, the problem is actually with `/bin/bash -c`. It assumes that the command we wish to run is in form of string just after the option. However, this means the the options/arguments must also be in a string.

So, for instance
`/bin/bash -c ls -l` won't ls in list mode .

But `/bin/bash -c "ls -l"` will.

But since your argument will be appended at the last of the command, it won't go through. So, for that try doing this,
`/bin/bash -c 'ls $0' -l`. see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144519/285765) for more details.

So, basically to pass an argument I made this files. (just to make sure I was right)

`script`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $VARIABLE $1
```

`env`

```
#!/bin/bash

export VARIABLE="Hello"
```

`dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY script .
COPY env .
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c","source ./env && ./script $0"]
```

And after using the `docker build test .` command I ran, `docker run test world`
and I got `Hello world`

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! This helped me fix the issue, and involved minimal change to existing script.

Answer (score 0):

**A pure answer:** Docker containers already provide a separate isolated filesystem space with their own space for Python libraries to be installed, separate from the system Python and other containers; you don't need to install a virtual environment inside a Docker image.  If you just skip everything related to virtual environments and make sure your script is executable, you can run it directly as the ENTRYPOINT, and it will see the "command" as `sys.argv`.

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt # as "system" packages
COPY . ./
RUN chmod +x my_script.py
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/my_script.py"]
```

You need to make sure the first line of your Python script contains a "shebang" line so the system knows it's Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ...
def main(): ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**An all-Python answer:** If you write a `setup.py` script, it can [generate wrapper scripts](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) that will launch some specific Python module.  Even if you install this in a virtual environment, you can run the script directly without activating the virtual environment, and it will work.

So your `setup.py` might say:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_script = my_module.my_script:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

Then your Dockerfile can say

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN python -m venv env
RUN ./env/bin/pip install .
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/env/bin/my_script"]
```

**A minimal answer:** You can move extended setup in an `sh -c '...'` invocation into a shell script.  (You hint at this in your question.)  So long as the script is executable and contains an appropriate `#!/path/to/interpreter` line at the very beginning, you can just run it directly and it will understand command-line arguments appropriately.  So that script can be as little as

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# activate the virtual environment
# "." is POSIX standard and equivalent to bash-specific "source"
. env/bin/activate

# run the actual script, passing our command-line arguments on to it
exec python my_script.py "$@"
```

Then your Dockerfile looks like

```
...
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```